# Using ruby sqlite to insert to table within a loop which is part of a method

Tags: ruby, sqlite, methods, insert

I'm struggling to loop through an "INSERT INTO" sqlite statement within a Ruby method. Please advice. My code is shown below. The error messages seem to suggest that Ruby doesn't recognise the db object within the method?? Apologies for being a bit of a noob but I've trawled through the internet and I couldn't find the answer :(

```
require "sqlite3"
require "nokogiri"

begin

db = SQLite3::Database.new('RM.db')
db.execute "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Properties(address TEXT, askingPrice TEXT)"

def get_property_list(newpage, dbname)
    resultspage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(newpage))
    details = resultspage.css("div.details.clearfix")
    count_items = details.count
    puts "there are #{count_items} items on this page"

    for i in 0..count_items-1
        address = resultspage.css("span.displayaddress")[i]
        asking_price = resultspage.css("p.price")[i]

        puts address.text
        puts asking_price.text

        dbname.execute "INSERT INTO Properties VALUES(#{address}, #{asking_price})"

    end
end

get_property_list("someurl.com", db)

    rows = db.execute("select * from Properties")
    p rows

ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting either value in your INSERT. You shouldn't be using string interpolation for SQL at all, use bound parameters and always specify the column names too:

```
dbname.execute 'INSERT INTO Properties (address, askingPrice) VALUES (?, ?)', address, asking_price
```

Or you could prepare a statement and use it over and over again:

```
insert = dbname.prepare('INSERT INTO Properties (address, askingPrice) VALUES (?, ?)')
for i in 0..count_items-1
  #...
  insert.execute(address, asking_price)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the errors you've highlighted but I'm still getting errors. Seems like the problem is that the method which contains the INSERT INTO statement doesn't recognise the db object which I created outside of the method. Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you getting? How are you calling the function?